# Why EF tries to convert List<Type> to Type when saving an object with a list of related objects (1 to many)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

When I try to save a Consumption object by calling `context.Consumption.Add(myConsumption)` and then `context.SaveChanges()`, I get a System.InvalidCastException. I have no clue why EF wants to cast the `List<Payment>` to `Payment`, since the Payments property of Consumption is of type `List<Payment>`.

```
    public class Consumption {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       ...
       public virtual List<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
    }

    public class Payment {
       ...
       [ForeignKey("Id")]
       public Consumption Consumption { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. We cannot help you by only looking at the entities

Comment: What makes you think the EF "wants" to cast the `List<Payment>` to `Payment` ?

Comment: I think your annotations might be wrong, and your relationship isnt correct

Comment: I'm getting an InvalidCastException that says: Cannot implicitly cast System.Collection.Generic.List`1[Payment] to Payment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have things a little out of wack

Assuming you have the following design

```
public class Consumption 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   ...
   public virtual List<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
}

public class Payment {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public Consumption Consumption { get; set; }
   public int ConsumptionId { get; set; }
}
```

EF is smart enough to figure out the relationship and database scaffolding based on naming convention

However if you need to use Annotations, then you need to make a decision of how you are telling EF about your relationship

```
public class Payment {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public Consumption Consumption { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("Consumption")] // point to the FK to the navigation property
   public int ConsumptionId { get; set; }
}
```

Or

```
public class Payment {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("ConsumptionId")] // point to the navigation property to the FK
   public Consumption Consumption { get; set; }
   public int ConsumptionId { get; set; }
}
```

Or

```
public class Consumption 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   ...
   [ForeignKey("ConsumptionId")]  // Point to the dependent FK
   public virtual List<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
}
```

My suspicion is that in your database (and this should be easy to check) you just have a singular `foreign key` in your `Consumption` table for `payment`

You seem to be pointing to the `Primary key` of your Payments table. However musings aside, it surprises me that EF even let you do this migration (if i'm reading this correctly)